# How common is it for 20th Century Fox to modify their ident like they did for Bohemian Rhapsody?

Tags: bohemian-rhapsody

For Bohemian Rhapsody, the Freddie Mercury biopic, 21st Century Fox [enlisted the current lineup of Queen](http://www.noise11.com/news/queen-also-did-the-20th-century-fox-theme-for-bohemian-rhapsody-20181229) to re-record the famous 20th Century Fox fanfare theme with a Queen twist (the finished product can be seen in that link, along with Queen's Brian May recording the reaction of moviegoers seeing it for the first time).

How unprecedented was this on the part of 20th Century Fox? I can't in my memory remember this ever being done before, and the only 20th Century Fox fanfare I've seen is the one I've grown up seeing. How commonly does 20th Century Fox change the fanfare theme to coincide with a movie or special event?

Comment: I have seen them mess with the intro before in recent times, though, even if the specific examples eldue me right now.

Comment: The Greatest Showman first shows the classical version, then cuts abruptly to a modern version with the opening music from the movie. Interesting example since it, in some sense, shows two interesting variations: the 1950's version in a (2017?) film, and the modern version with different music in black-and-white https://youtu.be/Kv6H9f8JcG8

Comment: The first one that comes to my mind is the one for [The Simpsons Movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NDgUC3NPX4). Everybody loved it at the theater

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is done somewhat commonly.

There is even a [TV Tropes article](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/LogoJoke/TwentiethCenturyFox) listing out various examples.

A few examples provided here:

X-Men: Days of Future Past:

The Peanuts Move:

And I don't know if you are only asking about the music, or including the visuals as well, but Moulin Rouge! changed the visuals for it:

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89985/discussion-on-answer-by-gendoikari-how-common-is-it-for-20th-century-fox-to-modi).